# How to add two different layouts to Listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-imageview, android-image

I want to develop an interface like WhatsApp chat.

I implemented the whole interface with `ListView`. I can able to add text to `ListView`. But I don't know how to add an image to the same `ListView` as an attachment.

My main aim is to add text, images, audio files, and video files to single `ListView`.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the answer.

Here is my code for combining the TextView and ImageView in ListView:
[adding-more-than-two-different-layouts-to-listview.html](http://androidprogramsforyou.blogspot.in/2015/07/adding-more-than-two-different-layouts.html)

Answer (score 0):

So if understand the question well, you would like to load an image from the SDcard or from the gallery and load into a listview item`s imageview, right ?

Load image from file:

```
File imgFile = new  File("/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg");

if(imgFile.exists()){

Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);

myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
```

or if you would like to select from gallery:

```
public void pickImage() {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  intent.setType("image/*");
  startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_PHOTO_FOR_AVATAR);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_PHOTO_FOR_AVATAR && resultCode ==         Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    if (data == null) {
        //Display an error
        return;
    }
    InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
    //Now you can do whatever you want with your inpustream, save it as file, upload to a server, decode a bitmap...
}
}
```

You can call these methods from the listview onItemClick listener, and return with the Bitmap, when you are finished the loading of the image.

Comment: but how to combine text list view and image list view dynamically